# How can I link to an internal image within a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using Firefox SDK.

The following code works, so at least I know everything is working as it's supposed to:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").src="http://somesite/externalimage.jpg";
```

However, Mozilla isn't approving this version of my extension, because I'm linking to an external image.

So what I have to do is link to the image inside the extension (I uploaded the same image to inside the extension).

I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").src=" + data.url("externalimage.jpg") + ";
```

So how do I link to an image inside the extension?

Comment: `document.getElementById("mydiv").src=" + data.url("externalimage.jpg") + ";` is not valid JavaScript syntax. Have you tried the syntactically-correct form `document.getElementById("mydiv").src = data.url("externalimage.jpg");`?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your syntax is wrong and that will error. It should be:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").src = data.url("externalimage.jpg");
```

Are you including the data module from self?

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
```

What context is this in? Your main SDK code has access to the data.url function, but if this is in a content script, you won't have it there, you'll need to pass in the value with a message

In main.js

```
// Assuming a pagemod here, but can be any worker
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
var { PageMod } = require('sdk/page-mod');
PageMod({
  include: '*',
  contentScriptFile: data.url('script.js'),
  onAttach: function (worker) {
    worker.port.emit('link', data.url('externalimage.png');
  }
});
```

In content script, script.js:

```
self.port.on('link', function (url) {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").src = url;
});
```

Comment: INTERNAL IMAGE NOT EXTERNAL!

Comment: What? This is an internal image, just change the name of the png. Can you explain?

Comment: @user2651403 `data.url` will return an absolute-path internal data URL, so I don't understand how your comments about relative paths apply here. If you're using a content script (you don't specify, so we must guess), this answer addresses that case as well.  From everything you've said so far, this answer looks like it correctly addresses all of your listed concerns, so please [edit] your question with more details if you don't find it satisfactory.

Comment: Oh I saw you changed this awhile ago and added more specific details. I'll try the new solution and get back to you. Because the relative url works in the main.js but not in the content script. I see you provided a way to circumvent the issue in your updated answer.

Comment: @user2651403 This question has no edit history; this has always been the text of this answer. You probably meant to post your comments on the other, totally separate answer below, which *does* contain the faults you mention.

Comment: Yea, I think I did mean to post them on the other answer not realizing it was a new answer. Haven't had the time to test it yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a relative url.  If the html file and the image file are both located in the `/data/` folder.  Then the following should work:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").src="some-image.jpg"
```

Comment: DOES NOT WORK. -
It was the first thing I tried, which is why I'm coming here. Because RELATIVE URL does Not Work.